# Pipe two or more shell commands in C using a loop

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm trying to execute `ls | wc -l` through a program in C, instead of using the command line.
This is my current working code:

```
int main() { 
   int pfds[2]; 
   pipe(pfds); 
   pid_t pid = fork(); 
   if ( pid == 0 ) { /* The child process*/ 
      close(1);
      dup(pfds[1]);
      close(pfds[0]);
      execlp("ls", "ls", NULL); 
   } else { /* The parent process*/ 
      close(0);
      dup(pfds[0]);
      close(pfds[1]);
      wait(0);
      execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL); 
   } 
   return 0; 
}
```

How would I rewrite this code to work with a for-loop?

For example:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {

    // Rewrite the 2-level pipe here

}
```

Later, I would like to extend the for loop to execute more processes piped together like `a | b | c | ...`

Comment: Do you want to use the `for` loop to run `ls | wc -l` N times instead of one (in your example 2)?

Comment: For simple two-command pipe it doesn't matter, are you trying to solve this for a more generic pipe of unknown length?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes, i'm trying to solve this for a more generic pipe

Comment: @HMemon I think you misunderstood my question. I am asking if you want to run the exact same piped processes (`ls | wc -l`) multiple times. Do you want to do *that*, or do you want to use the `for` loop to execute *more* processes piped together like `a | b | c | ...`? It's unclear what you're asking. You should specify this in your question.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I want to use the for loop to execute more processes piped together like a | b | c | ...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to extend the for loop to execute more processes piped together like a | b | c | ..

Comment: regarding: `wait(0);
      execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);`   What is the program waiting on, before executing a `execlp()`?

Comment: OT: always check the returned value from a call to `pipe()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there are three(3) kinds of returned values from `fork()` the program needs to check all 3 kinds.

Comment: to get the output from `ls` to feed into `wc`  both processes need to be executing.  Therefore, should not `wait()` for `ls` to complete before starting `wc`.  However, note that `execlp()` does not return unless an error occurs.  So each call to `execlp()` should be followed by: `perror( "execlp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: The posted code does not compile!.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service.  Please post what you have tried and why it does not do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to pipe multiple commands together, you'll need to keep the parent running to keep `fork()`ing for each command.

Using a `for` loop, you will need to do this for the first `n - 1` commands (the last one will be executed in the main program):

1. Create a pipe.
2. Execute `fork()`.
3. In the child: overwrite standard input with the read end of the *previous* pipe, and standard output with the write end of the current pipe.
4. In the child: execute `execve()`.
5. In the parent: close unneeded pipes and save read end of current pipe to be used in the next iteration.

Then, after the loop ends, overwrite standard input with the read end of the last pipe and execute `execve()` of the last command.

---

Below I've written a simple working example that executes:

```
ls | wc -l | xargs printf "0x%x\n" | cowsay
```

It should work for any number of commands (including only 1 single command).

**NOTE**: I did not add error checks in this code apart for `execvp()` just to make it short, but you should definitely check for errors after each call to `pipe()`, `dup2()`, `fork()` and any other function.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_ARGC 3

int main(void) {
    char *commands[][MAX_ARGC + 1] = {
        {"ls", NULL},
        {"wc", "-l", NULL},
        {"xargs", "printf", "0x%x\n", NULL},
        {"cowsay", NULL}
    };

    size_t i, n;
    int prev_pipe, pfds[2];

    n = sizeof(commands) / sizeof(*commands);
    prev_pipe = STDIN_FILENO;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        pipe(pfds);

        if (fork() == 0) {
            // Redirect previous pipe to stdin
            if (prev_pipe != STDIN_FILENO) {
                dup2(prev_pipe, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(prev_pipe);
            }

            // Redirect stdout to current pipe
            dup2(pfds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(pfds[1]);

            // Start command
            execvp(commands[i][0], commands[i]);

            perror("execvp failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Close read end of previous pipe (not needed in the parent)
        close(prev_pipe);

        // Close write end of current pipe (not needed in the parent)
        close(pfds[1]);

        // Save read end of current pipe to use in next iteration
        prev_pipe = pfds[0];
    }

    // Get stdin from last pipe
    if (prev_pipe != STDIN_FILENO) {
        dup2(prev_pipe, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(prev_pipe);
    }

    // Start last command
    execvp(commands[i][0], commands[i]);

    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Output on my machine (since `ls` printed 41 lines and 41 = 0x29):

```
 ______
< 0x29 >
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```